# Jquery, CSS: How do I resize a set of fixed elements to dynamically fill the remaining height of the browser window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, resize

Basically, I have a set of fixed elements that start 180px from the top of the page.  They're all stacked, and I use another set of functions to hide/unhide them accordingly to emulate tabs.  They all belong to the same class 'editor_view'.  I want each of them to terminate at the bottom of the page.

What would the code for this look like in Jquery, exactly?  I know it would involve 'resize()', 'height()', and possibly 'position()', but I'm still not adept enough with Jquery to assemble this all together just yet.

**Edit:** And by dynamic, I mean even if the browser window size changes.  To an extent, of course (like 200px minimum height or something).